# Extension of the Green-Tao theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-progressions

The Green-Tao theorem asserts that for any $k$, there exists an arithmetic progression of length $k$ consisting only of primes. What I was wondering, is whether it has been proven whether there are infinitely many such progressions for any $k$, or for some $k$, the number of prime-only progressions of length $k$ is finite.

Comment: Did you look at their paper? It is at  https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0404188.pdf. See Theorem 1.2.

Answer (score 2):

It is trivial to see that we will get infinitely many. Just consider prime AP's of length nk where you choose n. Then u get n such prime AP's of length k trivially.

Comment: Why does it have to be of length $nk$? Couldn't it also be length $n+k$?

Comment: Yes of course pick ur favourite one